# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2/11/2014 4:25:27 PM' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using a sql datasource to update a table from another table.  my update query is

```
UPDATE    table1
SET table1.brnlimit = table2.brnlimit, table1.tellimit = table2.tellimit
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN
limit ON table1.Branch = table2.Branch AND MONTH(table1.entered) = MONTH(table2.month) AND MONTH(table1.entered) = @mo
```

From that datasource query itself, it runs perfectly.  Updating the records by month, however when I run the website, the sqldatasource.update() call gives me the conversion failed error.  I am at a loss, because I am not converting anything, just stripping out data (maybe I am wrong).  At any rate, does anyone have a suggestion that may help me get past this?  Thanks!

Comment: seems like you are passing in the date string, not the month datepart.

Comment: What is the value of `@mo`?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add that the @mo parameter is filled by the calendar_selectionchanged sub and fills a label with the Month (numeric) value.  lblmonth.text=calpicker.selecteddate.month  I'm sure that is probably the issue, I am just not sure how to fix it.  My SQL is rusty.  Sorry

Comment: Also the columns entered and month are datetime datatypes.  If that helps at all.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to convert the selecteddate to a datetime, then get the month

so try this ...

AND MONTH(table1.entered) = MONTH(CAST(@mo AS DATETIME))

Comment: Awesome, your a life saver!  Changed my sub to
        TextBox2.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate
and then added your code onto my sql parameter, and it works beautifully!  Thanks again!!